# join 2 tables to bring multiple column's using some case

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `table1`

```
 pid_x | pid_y | count
-------|-------|-------
 a     | b     |  5
 a     | c     | 10
 b     | a     | 20
 c     | e     |  3
 d     | g     |  7
 e     | f     | 10
 e     | b     | 20
```

and so on (more than 1 million rows)

Also I have a `master_table`
 which consists details

```
 master_id | pid | rating_pid | price_pid
-----------|-----|------------|-----------
 a         | a1  |          2 | 10
 a         | b1  |          4 | 20
 a         | c1  |          1 | 30
 b         | d1  |        3.5 | 40
 b         | e1  |        2.4 | 50
 c         | f1  |        1.5 | 60
 d         | g1  |        3.8 | 70
```

(and so on, huge table  `master_table`)

you can see in table1, pid_x and pid_y have some values which are actually master_id(from master_table) and i want to replace the master_id with the cheapest 'pid' for that `master_id` in pid_x and pid_y

What i am looking for is, a `final_table`
which has columns

`pid_x   pid_y   count  price_pid_y  rating_pid_y    price_diff_pidy/x`

Explanation.

create a final table which has column's `pid_x` and `pid_y` after replacing the master_id values with cheapest pid from master_table and then join `price and rating` of pid_y from `master_table's` `pid` and also price difference percentage of pid_y with respect to pid_x.

`final_table`  should look something like this

```
 pid_x | pid_y | count | price_pid_y | rating_pid_y | price_diff_pid_y/x
-------|-------|-------|-------------|--------------|--------------------
 a1    | d1    |     5 |          40 |          3.5 |              400
 a1    | f1    |    10 |          60 |          1.5 |              600
 d1    | a1    |    20 |          10 |            2 |               25
```

I have a partial solution which gives me result,

i just want to add this condition "whenever in table1 pid_x and pid_y has values which are from master_id replace it with the cheapest pid from master_table".

```
SELECT
  t1.pid_x
  ,t1.pid_y
  ,t1.count
  ,m1.price_pid AS price_pid_y
  ,m1.rating_pid AS rating_pid_y
  ,100 * m1.price_pid / m2.price_pid AS price_diff_pid_y_x
FROM table1 t1
    INNER JOIN master_table m1 ON t1.pid_y = m1.pid
    INNER JOIN master_table m2 ON t1.pid_x = m2.pid
ORDER BY
  t1.pid_x
  ,t1.pid_y
```

Giving some case like

```
INNER JOIN master_table m1 
ON CASE WHEN A.pid_x = B.master_id
```

then replace that pid_x with cheapest pid dor that mater_id......`

Comment: This question is hard to understand.  You have tables but you have not bothered to line up the column names with the data values.  This means we have to guess what you mean.

Comment: you must clarify three things to let's know what's you mean:
first,the range of values in table1.pid_x and table1.pid_y is the same range of values in master_table.master_id?
second,do you want to replace pid_x using the value of master_table.pid where pid_x is equal master_table.master_id,and so dose pid_y?
third,what's your rule about cheapest 'pid',how can we judge which one is cheapest?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I understand so I am going to take this step by step so you can learn how to do it and fix the spots I did not understand.

First you want the "cheapest prices" when you look stuff up on the master table.  Lets make a query to get just that table.

First we get the unique identifier for that row:

```
 SELECT master_id, min(price_pid) as price_pid
 FROM master_table
 GROUP BY master_id
```

Then we can select that new table that only has one 1 which is the cheapest:

```
SELECT ma.* 
FROM master_table ma
JOIN (
  SELECT master_id, min(price_pid) as price_pid
  FROM master_table
  GROUP BY master_id
) as mi_ma on ma.master_id = mi_ma.master_id and ma.price_pid = mi_ma.price_pid
```

I would now create this as a view like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW min_master_table AS
  SELECT ma.* 
  FROM master_table ma
  JOIN (
    SELECT master_id, min(price_pid) as price_pid
    FROM master_table
    GROUP BY master_id
  ) as mi_ma on ma.master_id = mi_ma.master_id and ma.price_pid = mi_ma.price_pid
```

With this new view your query is very close, here it is fixed:

```
SELECT
  m1.pid as pid_x,
  m2.pic as pid_y,
  t1.count,
  m2.price_pid AS price_pid_y,
  m2.rating_pid AS rating_pid_y,
  100 * m2.price_pid / m1.price_pid AS price_diff_pid_y_x
FROM table1 t1
JOIN min_master_table m1 ON t1.pid_x = m1.pid
JOIN min_master_table m2 ON t1.pid_y = m2.pid
```

> NOTE:  If you can't make the view this will also work but it is a lot more prone to error because of code duplication:

```
SELECT
  m1.pid as pid_x,
  m2.pic as pid_y,
  t1.count,
  m2.price_pid AS price_pid_y,
  m2.rating_pid AS rating_pid_y,
  100 * m2.price_pid / m1.price_pid AS price_diff_pid_y_x
FROM table1 t1
JOIN (
  SELECT ma.* 
  FROM master_table ma
  JOIN (
    SELECT master_id, min(price_pid) as price_pid
    FROM master_table
    GROUP BY master_id
  ) as mi_ma on ma.master_id = mi_ma.master_id and ma.price_pid = mi_ma.price_pid
) m1 ON t1.pid_x = m1.pid
JOIN (
  SELECT ma.* 
  FROM master_table ma
  JOIN (
    SELECT master_id, min(price_pid) as price_pid
    FROM master_table
    GROUP BY master_id
  ) as mi_ma on ma.master_id = mi_ma.master_id and ma.price_pid = mi_ma.price_pid
) m2 ON t1.pid_y = m2.pid
```